# How to use django-select2 widgets in django admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, jquery-select2, django-select2

In my django app I have modified the User entity to include a worker field (OneToOneField). But from the django admin site that field yiels so many result , so it is difficult for the logged user to select a worker. Is there any way to use the select2 (ModelSelect2Widget) widgets from the django admin site?
For any regular form I have define the widgets in the following way:

```
from django_select2.forms import ModelSelect2Widget
    class ProcessForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = ProcessModel
            exclude = ('id',)
    
            widgets = {
                'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'code':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'description':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'geom': LeafletWidget(),
                'product': ModelSelect2Widget(model=ProductModel, queryset=ProductModel.objects.filter(),
                                                search_fields=['name__icontains'],
                                                attrs={'style': 'width: 100%;'}), 
    }
```

Is there any way to use the ModelSelect2Widget for the worker field in the admin site form?
Here is my code:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    worker = models.OneToOneField(WorkerModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                related_name="user", verbose_name=_("Trabajador"), null=True, blank=True)

    
    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        verbose_name="Usuario"
        verbose_name_plural="Usuarios"
        permissions = (
            ("secretario", "Secretario(a)"),
            ("director", "Director"),
        
        )
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class UserAdminInherited(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Worker info'), {'fields': ('worker',)}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

admin.site.register(User, UserAdminInherited)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since **Django 2.0.**, we can use [**`autocomplete_fields`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields).

> autocomplete_fields is a list of ForeignKey and/or ManyToManyField
> fields you would like to change to **[Select2](https://select2.org/)** autocomplete inputs.

**`ModelAdmin`**(is parent of `UserAdmin`) has the property [**`autocomplete_fields`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields)):

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User = get_user_model()


class UserAdminInherited(UserAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['worker']
    ...


admin.site.register(User, UserAdminInherited)
```

> You must define **[search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields)** on the related object’s **ModelAdmin**
> because the autocomplete search uses it.

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(WorkerModel)
class WorkerModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['model_field']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just posted a new question about django-select2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68660349/i-cannot-set-a-value-to-django-select2-modelselect2widget-using-val-function